# Changing Machine Type on Google Cloud

Tags: virtual-machine, instance, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am looking to upgrade the machine type on my Google Cloud. The handful of solutions I've found all mentioned the follow:

1) Delete old instance while preserving disk.

2) Create new instance using the disk from the old instance.

None of the solutions provide any details though. How do you accomplish the 2 steps above in detail? I created a test instance (Bitnami LAMP stack), then tried deleting it, but it didn't give me any option to "preserve disk" when deleting, or "select another disk" during creation.

I'm not sure if it matters, but my instance is created via Bitnami (it's a LAMP deployment).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a YouTube video posted by Google Cloud Platform walking through these steps.  https://youtu.be/-XYUeORywXU

The basic steps are:

- Create snapshot of your disk
- Create new instance with the desired type
- Change boot disk on new instance to the snapshot you created
- Delete old machine once new instance is up