# How to copy database from one instance to another on google compute engine?

Tags: mongodb, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I created a MongoDB instance on google cloud. The machine type is n1-standard-2 (2 vCPUs, 7.5 GB memory). This is eating up too many resources. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373257/how-to-change-a-machine-type-on-google-compute-engine) but I didn't understand the accepted answer. How would we delete the old instance making sure the disk isn't deleted and how would we use that disk on the new instance?

Comment: This post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169329/changing-machine-type-on-google-cloud) has the steps to change your machine type. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intention is to just upgrade the instance so as to cope up with the requirements of MongoDB usage, you can as of today on GCE upgrade the instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33682236/3525524